# How to conditionally stop a JavaScript generator?

Tags: javascript, c#, iterator, generator

With an iterator like the following one:

```
function* idMaker(){
    let index = 0;
    while(index < 3)
        yield index++;
}
```

How can I make sure to stop the generator prematurely based on a condition?

```
function* idMaker(){
    let index = 0;
    while(index < 3)
        if (checker(index))
            yield index++;
        else
            return;
}
```

Is it okay appropriate to use in a generator? Should I use `break` instead of `yield break` perhaps like in C#?

Can you include a link to MDN or spec where this is discussed?

Comment: Anything that terminates the function will work. I don't think there are any best practices around that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've decided to verify this experimentally with the following code:

```
function checker(i) {
  return i !== 2;
}

function* idMakerReturn(){
    let index = 0;
    while(index < 3)
        if (checker(index))
            yield index++;
        else
            return;
}

function* idMakerBreak(){
    let index = 0;
    while(index < 3)
        if (checker(index))
            yield index++;
        else
            break;
}

const a = idMakerReturn();
console.log('1', a.next());
console.log('2', a.next());
console.log('3', a.next());

const b = idMakerBreak();
console.log('1', b.next());
console.log('2', b.next());
console.log('3', b.next());
```

Both variants correctly return `{ "done": true, "value": undefined }` when broken out from. I did also check this with TypeScript by observing the inferred function type.

```
function* idGen(seed: string | undefined) {
  if (!seed) {
    return; // Or `break`
  }

  const something = seed.trim();
}
```

With `return` everything works correctly and the function return type is `IterableIterator<T>`.

With `break` I am asked to provide a label to jump to and also `something` is no longer inferred to be safe to access (just `string` because the `undefined` is handled by the `if`), but remains a `string | undefined`.

This leads me to conclude that as Felix says, anything that terminates the generator function will correctly yield the `done: true` item, but it seems that `return` is preferable because escape analysis works with it whereas it doesn't with `break`.

Still have not been able to find official word on this, but it's good enough for me.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to take a look to the `return` method of generators?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/return

```
function* gen() { 
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

const g = gen();

g.next();        // { value: 1, done: false }
g.return('foo'); // { value: "foo", done: true }
g.next();        // { value: undefined, done: true }
g.return('bar'); // { value: "bar", done: true }
```

Comment: I specifically care about the `yield` syntax and its equivalent within the generator implementation for breaking out of it.

Comment: Did you think to use the yield inside the generator as normally, get a reference to the generator and then stop the generator from outside checking a condition and calling return?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but I'm looking for library use so the generator needs not to push any responsibilities onto the call site.

Comment: Oh ok got it. Have you tried to call it internally using the this reference? Inside your condition for stopping you call this.return()

Comment: Because actually following the standards you should use the return method of itself to stop the execution, not break or any other trick

Comment: I see your point about the standard, but surely having a sugar for `next()` - `yield x;` must have a counterpart for `return()` - the actual `return;`? I'd like to stick with sugar unless there's something broken about using `return;`

Comment: Nope I think that you could try the return method of the generator, it should be different from the standard return one, but give me a sec to double check

Comment: Yep it seems so. Having lunch now I.ll try your code calling the return method within the generator once in front of the computer.

Comment: in this other example you can also check from outside if the generator has done its job: https://jsfiddle.net/bqw6aujo/6/